# Access webcam of sleeping Mac in ssh with FFmpeg

Tags: macos, ssh, ffmpeg, webcam, sleep-mode

I am able from my Macbook to ssh my remote Macmini which is ON (logged in and not sleeping) and use my webcam with a command like `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0:0" out.avi` however, when the remote Macmini is logged out (or/and sleeping) ffmpeg gives me an error that it cannot use the webcam `Failed to create AV capture input device: Cannot use PC-LM1E`. Any workaround? I want to check on my pets while out of my house and would like to keep the Macmini at sleep.

Thanks I advance.

Comment: Well, I was hoping some detailed explanation because this is not helping. Does the remote computer has to be connected with ethernet? How to use WOL? should I install WOL to my remote computer? from what I read online I do not understand how to use WOL.

Comment: So I tried the script wakeuplan also an app called WakeOnCommand and both don't work. After reading a bit I suspect there might be some port issue? Anyways I give up, however it sounds crazy to me that I am logged into my computer in ssh, I can control everything but cannot wake it up! thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: I assumed you couldn't SSH into the remote machine while it was asleep, but it appears I was mistaken. In that case WOL isn't the right approach. Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. You'll probably get better help for this question at [apple.se].